# java -Dlog4j.configuration command not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, log4j

i have a problem with Hadoop mapreduce in R, and in the logs i did find this :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
```

my problem is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052643/hadoop-job-log4jwarn-please-initialize-the-log4j-system-properly) with no reaction unfortunately , so after a lot of research i found that i need to tell where to find the log4j with this command :

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:path/log4j.properties
```

my question is WHERE , because i did this :
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties
but in my terminal in ubuntu it shows me that i didn"t use java command correctly , nothing shows that the command workd or not , the output is like this :

```
usage: java [-option]class [args ...]
....
```

so i don't know where to type this command , any help will be apreciated .
 thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know log4j does not need a URL to its path.

Try this instead:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=/home/user/log4j.properties
```

(Or whereever you stored the file)

Try to set up this before you start your application:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j...
```

What you are trying to do is basically configuring java parameters. There are examples here on stackoverflow how to do this for other parameters, you will find more examples here: [xlConnect R use of JVM memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766981/xlconnect-r-use-of-jvm-memory)

Comment: i did : export JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties , and i get : -su : export : ..... not a valid identifier

Comment: it's ok , i did like this : export =" ..."
so do i need to add -Dlog4j.configuration again in terminal or just export java=".." ?

Comment: `export JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties`, no su, no sudo, no nothing. You can check with `echo $JAVA_OPTS` if they have been set and then run your application from the same shell

Comment: yes i did it , it just need to add "" : 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties"
i need to run the app from Rstudio not from the shell

Comment: If you run rstudio from the shell and then the app from rstudio the environment variables are supposed to be handed over.

Comment: please see the link above , i have another error with the package functional.

Answer (score 5):

I had a same trouble and solved by reading the [Log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

> Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if 
>   set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory 
>   that matches the file extension.

So the option name is "log4j.configuration**File**", not "log4j.configuration".

My application is not Hadoop but just an Java Servlet. But I hope this post help you and others.

Comment: The setting is different depending on the version:
log4j uses log4j.configuration http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.5
log4j2 uses log4j.configurationFile or log42j.configurationFile https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Sharing for posterity.

Keynote for Windows users:

1. If the Logback configuration file location exists inside the classpath

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:"C:\Code\repos\logback.xml"
```

2. If the Logback configuration file location does not exist inside  the classpath

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:"C:\Code\repos\logback.xml"
```