# R (XLConnect) Merge all worksheet into one if size of worksheet is huge

Tags: r, excel, import, xlconnect

I want to merge all unknown number of worksheets into one csv. Here is my attempt.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )
library(XLConnect)
xlcMemoryReport() 
xlcFreeMemory()
xlcMemoryReport() 
wb=loadWorkbook(exelfiles[i])         
df=do.call(rbind,lapply(getSheets(wb),function(sheet)readWorksheet(wb,sheet)))
write.csv(df,"final.csv",row.names=F)
```

If size of excel file is small, it is working. But not working for larger excel files. Following it is returning

```
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: I would give a try to `xlsx` package.

Comment: See Martin Studer's (package author) comment in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766981/xlconnect-r-use-of-jvm-memory. For reading, package readxl is another good choice, and very fast.